# Draw bitmap to canvas, being the main activity?

Tags: android

I want to draw a bitmap to the canvas.
However, I am an inexperienced programmer and don't know how to make the canvas the main screen.
Basically, I want to draw a bitmap to the main activity using a canvas. I know how to draw bitmaps to canvases but it doesn't show up anywhere that I can see (with only one activity). I want the bitmap to show up on the main activity. Any tips?

Sorry if the wording is confusing, thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want the Bitmap to be full screen on your main activity screen?

Comment: @Neil no I was going to have it appear in random places on the screen. So far I got it to draw a bitmap on a canvas at random x and y coordinates within the screens resolution, but then I try to draw it to a canvas. I don't know how to connect the canvas I am drawing on to what I am actually seeing

Answer (score 2):

see these links. might think they may be helpful.

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/707993-how-to-draw-2d-object-in-android-with-a-canvas

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/703911-2d-drawing-with-android-motion-sensors

Answer (score 1):

you can try searching online..

some example

http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame2.html

or some game engine which will help you to develop game with proper memory management.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163446/what-is-the-best-2d-game-engine-for-android

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is create your own CustomView. When you are putting a button or anything in your layout file that is actually a view. Android does allow you to create your own view to manually handle things on the screen. Games are usually implemented that way. They use customview by extending SurfaceView/GLSurfaceView.

As for the solution of your problem:

- create a custom view by extending the View.
- add all the constructor from superclass.
- override onDraw method
- onDraw method will pass you a canvas for you to draw
- draw whatever you like(Bitmap, line ,....) using canvas

In your layout file include the customview you just created.

```
<my.packagename.MyCustomView android:width .... > </my.packagename.MyCustomView>
```

Hope this helps.
Also you will find lots good resources on how you can create your own customview.